# Extract first position of a regex match grep

Tags: awk, grep

Good morning everyone,

I have a text file containing multiple lines. I want to find a regular pattern inside it and print its position using grep.

For example:

```
ARTGHFRHOPLIT
GFRTLOPLATHLG
TGHLKTGVARTHG
```

I want to find L[any_letter]T in the file and print the position of L and the three letter code. In this case it would results as:

```
11 LIT
8 LAT
4 LKT
```

I wrote a code in grep, but it doesn't return what I need. The code is:

```
grep -E -boe "L.T" file.txt
```

It returns:

```
11:LIT
21:LAT
30:LKT
```

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: What should the output be if the input was `ALLTTB` - `2:LLT` or `2:LLT\n3:LTT` or something else?

Comment: @EdMorton It should be 2 LLT\n3 LTT, But I tried with the answer of anubhava and it found only the first triplet

Comment: That's why I asked - you had only included 1 sunny day case in your sample input/output and then accepted an answer that didn't do what I thought you probably wanted for other cases. It's important to try to come up with the non-trivial cases when posting sample input/output for questions, e.g. multiple matches on a line and/or overlapping matches. There may be others I haven't considered, idk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Awk suites this better:

```sh
awk 'match($0, /L[[:alpha:]]T/) {
print RSTART, substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)}' file

11 LIT
8 LAT
4 LKT
```

This is assuming only one such match per line.

---

If there can be multiple *overlapping* matches per line then use:

```sh
awk '{
   n = 0
   while (match($0, /L[[:alpha:]]T/)) {
      n += RSTART
      print n, substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
      $0 = substr($0, RSTART + 1)
   }
}' file
```

Comment: Oh thanks!! In the case of multiple match per line how can I do?

Comment: I tried with your answer, but in the case of a sequence like ALLTTB it find only the first occurrence, so LLT and not LTT

Comment: @TiaCava: I have made an update to find overlapping matches like in `ALLTTB` check it now.

Comment: I have another question. Suppose that my file is:
ARTGHFRHOPL-ITL\n
GFRTL--OPLATHLG\n
TGHLKTGVARTHGKP

I want, as previously, find L[any_letter]T, skipping the - symbol, so that I'll obtain:

11 LIT\n
5 LOP
...

How can I make this?

Thanks in advance @anubhava

Comment: How is `LOP` to be found when match is ending with a `T`. May be you can do: `awk '{n=0; while (match($0, /L-?[[:alpha:]][PT]/)) {n += RSTART; print n, substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH); $0 = substr($0, RSTART+1)}}' file`

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`, should work in any `awk`.

```
awk '
{
  ind=prev=""
  while(ind=index($0,"L")){
    if(substr($0,ind+2,1)=="T" && substr($0,ind+1,1) ~ /[a-zA-Z]/){
      if(prev==""){ print prev+ind,substr($0,ind,3)   }
      if(prev>1)  { print prev+ind+2,substr($0,ind,3) }
    }
    $0=substr($0,ind+3)
  prev+=ind
  }
}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                                                     ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  ind=prev=""                                             ##Nullifying ind and prev variables here.
  while(ind=index($0,"L")){                               ##Run while loop to check if index for L letter is found(whose index will be stored into ind variable).
    if(substr($0,ind+2,1)=="T" && substr($0,ind+1,1) ~ /[a-zA-Z]/){      ##Checking condition if letter after 1 position of L is T AND letter next to L is a letter.
      if(prev==""){ print prev+ind,substr($0,ind,3)   }   ##Checking if prev variable is NULL then printing prev+ind along with 3 letters from index of L eg:(LIT).
      if(prev>1)  { print prev+ind+2,substr($0,ind,3) }   ##If prev is greater than 1 then printing prev+ind+2 and along with 3 letters from index of L eg:(LIT).
    }
    $0=substr($0,ind+3)                                   ##Setting value of rest of line value to 2 letters after matched L position.
  prev+=ind                                               ##adding ind to prev value.
  }
}'  Input_file                                            ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 2):

Peeking at the answer of [@anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava) you might also sum the RSTART + RLENGTH and use that as the start for the [substr](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) to get multiple matches per line and per word.

The while loop takes the current line, and for every iteration it updates its value by setting it to the part right after the last match till the end of the string.

Note that if you use the `.` in a regex it can match any character.

```
awk '{
  pos = 0
  while (match($0, /L[a-zA-Z]T/)) {
    pos += RSTART;
    print pos, substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
    $0 = substr($0, RSTART + RLENGTH)
   }
}' file
```

If file contains

```
ARTGHFRHOPLIT
GFRTLOPLATHLG
TGHLKTGVARTHG
ARTGHFRHOPLITLOT LATTELET
LUT
```

The output is

```
11 LIT
8 LAT
4 LKT
11 LIT
12 LOT
14 LAT
17 LET
1 LUT
```